# How can I close Slidable

Tags: flutter, dart

How can I close Slidable if I don't use SlidableAction(autoColose=true)?

```
Slidable(
          enabled: isEnableSlidable,
          key: const ValueKey(0),
          endActionPane: ActionPane(
            motion: const BehindMotion(),
            children: actionButton(
                status: widget.leaveRequest.status,
                leaveRequest: widget.leaveRequest,
                context: context),
          ),
          child: CardWidget(),
        ),
```